# Import text file into one dimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I import a text file, here the code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("stoplist.txt","r") or die("fail to open file");
    $stoplist;
    $i = 0;
    while($row = fgets($file)){
        $data = explode(",", $row);
        $stoplist[$i] = $data;
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($file);

print "<pre>";
print_r($stoplist);
print "</pre>"


?>
```

and it has an output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => able

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => about

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => above

        )
)
```

But I actually want a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => able
    [2] => about
    [3] => above
)
```

Do you have any suggestion for my problem?

Comment: `$stoplist[$i] = $data[0];`

Comment: can you show your txt file, make this value in one live and separated with " " space

Comment: Or just use `file` function

Comment: [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) before reinvent wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to convert your array into single Dimensional array:

```
$onedimension= call_user_func_array('array_merge', $stoplist);
print "<pre>";
print_r($onedimension);
```